# Replacing special characters

Tags: shell, unix, command, special-characters

I have a document which contains various special characters such as **Ã© Ã¿ Â° Ã† oÂºi**
I've written the following two commands which both work on 'single looking' characters such as **Ã Â± È**.

However neither of which work with the special characters listed above.

This command works using two byte hex decimals (To replace **Ã©** with **A**)

```
sed -i 's/\xc3\xA9/A/g' test.csv
```

This command uses utf8 to replace characters:

```
CHARS=$(python -c 'print u"\u00a9".encode("utf8")') sed -i 's/['"$CHARS"']/A/g' $filename
```

Either of these commands should work but neither do.

Comment: They are most probably not special characters but some data *misinterpreted* as being windows-1252 encoded when it is in fact utf-8 encoded. You should try and determine the encoding and read the data according to that encoding, instead of performing some random replacements. For example, “Ã©” is probably the utf-8 encoded form of the letter “é”, so it would be absurd to replace it by “A”.

Comment: Is there anyway of recoding this special data into utf-8 using a command?

Comment: It already *is* utf-8; your terminal or editor or whatever is treating is as some other encoding (windows-1252 or iso8859).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are viewing UTF-8 data as ISO-8859-1 (aka latin1).

This is what you'd experience when handling a UTF-8 encoded file in a ISO-8859-1 terminal:

```
$ cat file
The cafÃ© has crÃ¨me brÃ»lÃ©e.

$ iconv -f utf-8 -t iso-8859-1 < file
The café has crème brûlée.

$ iconv -c -f utf-8 -t ascii//ignore < file 
The caf has crme brle.
```

This usually only happens for PuTTY users, because PuTTY is one of the few terminal emulators that still uses ISO-8859-1 by default. You can set it to use UTF-8 in the PuTTY configuration.

Here's the same example in a UTF-8 terminal:

```
$ cat file
The café has crème brûlée.

$ iconv -f utf-8 -t iso-8859-1 < file
The caf� has cr�me br�l�e.

$ iconv -c -f utf-8 -t ascii//ignore < file 
The caf has crme brle.
```

The only correct solution is to fix your setup so that it uses UTF-8 throughout. ISO-8859-1 does not support the languages and features we take for granted today, and is not a useful option.